# Getting center of map JS google

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have recievig undefined for simply getting center of map in js. I have my map set up correctly and I am trying to get center of google map with the getCenter method. It is returning undefined. idk what I did wrong. here is my code.

```
           //map is defined earlier
          var center = map.getCenter()
          var lat = center.Latitude;
          var long = center.Longitude;
          console.log(lat + "," + long); //undefined
```

Comment: Do you want to get the center of the map when you for instance click a button or do you want to center the map at a specific location?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  How/when are you setting the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`center.Latitude` and `center.Longitude` does not exist. Use

```
var center = map.getCenter();
var lat = center.lat();
var lng = center.lng();
console.log(lat + "," + lng);
```

instead. Moreover I would recomment to change the variable name of the longitude to lon or lng, which is more common.
See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hvhs6md0/ for console ouput.